# Unable to install Python 3.9.10 on Linux 7

Tags: python-3.x, linux, openssl, python-3.9

Getting the below error while configuring python3.9.10 with the below command

**./configure --prefix=/opt/python3 --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl/include/openssl**

*checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl... no*

*checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works... no*

Using linux version 7 and openssl version OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022

Comment: What if you just use `--with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl`?

Comment: got the same error, since ssl.h was present under the given folder I gave till that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install **libssl-dev** in Debian/Ubuntu or **openssl-devel** in RH/CentOS

Comment: yum install openssl-devel. This worked for me. Thanks